# How to know whether all images are downloaded by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, dom-events

I am building divs dynamically with background images downloaded from a URL. The browser downloads and caches the images internally. How can I get notified when all images are downloaded?

```
function preloadContentScreenshots() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        var _row = content[i];
        for (var k = 0; k < _row.items.length; k++) {
            var _item = _row.items[k];
            var _div = document.createElement("div");
            _div.id = "content-screenshot-" + _item.id;
            _div.classList.add("cs");
            _div.classList.add("hidden");
            _div.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + _item.screenshots["1152x648"] + "')";
            document.getElementById("content-info-and-screenshot-container").appendChild(_div);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `service worker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. For demonstration, I made an array of images to test so I commented out part of your code. You get the idea though

```js
let content = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558211583-d26f610c1eb1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjY4NDE2fQ",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558459654-c430be5b0a44?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjY4NDE2fQ",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558834643-1dacaf774843?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjY4NDE2fQ"
]

let loadedImgs = 0;

function preloadContentScreenshots() {
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var _row = content[i];
    // for (var k = 0; k < _row.items.length; k++) {
    // var _item = _row.items[k];
    var _div = document.createElement("div");
    // _div.id = "content-screenshot-" + _item.id;
    _div.classList.add("cs");
    _div.classList.add("hidden");
    loadImage(_row, _div)

    document.getElementById("content-info-and-screenshot-container").appendChild(_div);
    //  }
  }
}

function loadImage(imageUrl, _div) {
  var bgImg = new Image();
  bgImg.onload = () => {
    _div.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgImg.src + "')";
    if (++loadedImgs >= content.length) {
      // all images are loaded
      console.log("all images loaded")
    }
  };
  // bgImg.src = _item.screenshots["1152x648"];
  bgImg.src = imageUrl;

}

preloadContentScreenshots()
```

```css
.cs {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id='content-info-and-screenshot-container'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kinglish, your answer helped me a lot in finding the solution. I had to use closure to make it work properly since I had to use for loops. I am marking your answer as the accepted answer.